# Issues with text position when printing to PNG in Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, png, matlab-figure

I have problems with text position when printing to PNG in matlab 2014b.

I am trying to create a simple plot using the code below:

```
size = [500 600];

%% Create figure
figure('units', 'pixels', 'position', [1 1 size], 'visible', 'on');
set(gcf, 'paperunits', 'points', 'paperposition', [1 1 size]);

%% Axes
axes('units', 'pixels', 'position', [50, 300, 400, 200], 'fontsize', 14, 'box', 'on');
plot([0 1], [0.5 0.5]);

text('units', 'normalized', 'position', [0.5 0.5], 'string', 'TEXT', 'fontsize', 14, 'verticalalignment', 'middle', 'horizontalalignment', 'center');

%% Print to png
filename = 'out.png';
fprintf('Printing to %s\n', filename);
print('-dpng', '-r0', filename);
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

When I change size to [500 900], the text doesn't appear in the middle of the plot:

[image]

Can anyone explain this? I run matlab with -nodisplay -nosplash options. The text starts moving away from the center when size is set to around 500x780

Comment: Possibly a bug with units setting. Did you try MathWorks support?

Comment: Yes, I have. No reply..  https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/183110-problems-with-text-position-when-printing-to-png-in-matlab-2014b